# Paste Functionality for WPF DataGrid with DataGridTemplateColumns

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I recently started using the WPF Datagrid with DataGridTemplateColumns containing the WPF AutoCompleteBox, but I'm finding trouble in implementing Clipboard.Paste functionality for these DataGridTemplateColumns.

I've managed to get Clipboard.Paste working with built-in DataGridColumns via Vishal's guide [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/archive/2008/09/25/pasting-content-to-new-rows-on-the-wpf-datagrid.aspx), but it doesn't work with DataGridTemplateColumns.

Delving into the OnPastingCellClipboardContent method in the DataGridColumn class, it appears that fe.GetBindingExpression(CellValueProperty) is returning null rather than the required BindingExpression.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

```
public virtual void OnPastingCellClipboardContent(object item, object cellContent)
    {
        BindingBase binding = ClipboardContentBinding;
        if (binding != null)
        {
            // Raise the event to give a chance for external listeners to modify the cell content
            // before it gets stored into the cell
            if (PastingCellClipboardContent != null)
            {
                DataGridCellClipboardEventArgs args = new DataGridCellClipboardEventArgs(item, this, cellContent);
                PastingCellClipboardContent(this, args);
                cellContent = args.Content;
            }

            // Event handlers can cancel Paste of a cell by setting its content to null
            if (cellContent != null)
            {
                FrameworkElement fe = new FrameworkElement();
                fe.DataContext = item;
                fe.SetBinding(CellValueProperty, binding);
                fe.SetValue(CellValueProperty, cellContent);

                BindingExpression be = fe.GetBindingExpression(CellValueProperty);

        be.UpdateSource();

    }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using ClipboardContentBinding and setting the binding's Mode to TwoWay, seems to works.

GetBindingExpression then returns something not null (the binding on ClipboardContentBinding) and the UpdateSource does not fail.

I imagine this solution is limited to the case where you have a PropertyChanged event triggered on the source, which in turn update the control in the column's DataTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

This is because for DataGridTemplateColumns there isnt a binding. The binding is taken care of in your datatemplate. The cell datatemplate just gets the item (the item in the row) and binds to it. there is no way for the column to know what is in the cell.

I have worked around this by creating my own columns. I derive from DataGridTextColumn (if i am doing one that has text input) and override the GenerateElement and GenerateEditingElement.

This way i still have the binding property that can be used for pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ClipboardContentBinding` as shown:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn 
    Header="First Name" 
    SortMemberPath="FirstName" 
    ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding FirstName}" 
    >
    <DatGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DatGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        ...
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Taken from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/687b6bfc-f559-4b79-ab16-5aee6163e4e7).

Comment: This won't work with WPFToolkit February 2010 release and possibly the other releases as well.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere, or did you find it out through testing?  `ClipboardContentBinding` exists as a property in [DataGridColumn.cs](http://wpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/40156#1544286)

Comment: I know that it exists and I have traced the error as far as the OP. If you look closely at the code the OP posted, then you'll realize that although ClipboardContentBinding is being used, it'll fail. I've written a workaround via reflection, as I didn't want to create a custom column. In short: No, does not work with template columns of WPFToolkit. I don't know about WPF with .NET 4, though.